# R filtering dataframes - match vector error

Tags: r, vector, filter, match

I am simply trying to filter columns of one dataframe based on another dataframe (only have columns that exists as rownames in support_1 dataframe). both editing_test and support_1 are dataframe. colnames(editing_test) and rownames(support_1) both look fine to me when checked separately.

Could anyone help me with this 'match' vector? I am really not sure what the problem possibly can be.

code

```
editing_test<-editing_test%>%filter(colnames %in% rownames(support_1))
```

Error

```
Error in `dplyr::filter()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = colnames %in% rownames(support_1)`.
Caused by error in `match()`:
! 'match' requires vector arguments
Backtrace:
 1. editing_test %>% ...
 9. colnames %in% rownames(support_1)
 Error in dplyr::filter(., colnames %in% rownames(support_1)) : 
Caused by error in `match()`:
! 'match' requires vector arguments
```

```
editing_test (dataframe) 

colnames    a   b    c
chr 1       0.1  1    2
chr 2       3   0.05  1
chr 3       5   3    2 


support_1 (dataframe)

rownames   data1    data2   data3
a           x        v       s
b           f         r      t
c           e        h       j


Thank you
```

Comment: Can you show your input example data.  Did you meant to `select` the columns instead of filtering the rows?  i.e. `editing_test %>% select(any_of(row.names(support_1))`

Comment: but woulnd't there be a way to do this with filter function?

Comment: According to `?filter` `The filter() function is used to subset a data frame, retaining all rows that satisfy your conditions`

Comment: Do you have any criteria to do this only with `filter`?

Comment: with your new data, there is a column called `colnames` in `support_1`, so the code would be `editing_test %>% select(any_of(support_1$colnames))`

Comment: i am so sorry, it is supposed to be rownames, not colnames (question is edited again). 
also, I am keeping the selected editing_test df later to run into this ```Error in as.vector(x, mode) : 
cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any' ``` Error, which i am not sure if it is rooted in the select(any_of ) function previously when selecting the cols for editing_test

Comment: Can you show your expected output based on the input showed

Comment: If the name is different `editing_test %>% select(any_of(support_1$rownames))`

Answer (score 1):

`filter` is used for filtering the rows.  If we need to subset the columns, use `select`

```
library(dplyr)
editing_test %>% 
   select(any_of(row.names(support_1)))
```